# Get value of a variable from another session in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, variables

How to share variables' values in org-mode between different sessions?

Simple example: in session *one* I create `_gpg_tmpdir`

```
#+name: make_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *one*
_gpg_tmpdir="$( mktemp -d )"
#+end_src
```

and need to clean up it in session *two*:

```
#+name: clean_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *two*
rm -rf $_gpg_tmpdir
#+end_src
```

The example is for the demonstration purpose only.
The question is what is the less painfull way to share variables between different code sessions (perhaps with different code languages) in org-mode.

Comment: Is this an `XY problem`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem Maybe clarify why you want to do this. The entire point of `sessions` is to keep things separate. If you must communicate between the two, this may not be an Org question but a general `how do I share data between bash processes` question.

Comment: You are right. I share data between bash sessions with something like `set > .state-0000` and `source .state-0000`. It works but I don't like it.

Comment: Many systems use something like that. State files, when filed correctly are fine. It's no worse than anything else. Everything is  a file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RESULTS` for the first session to write out the results, and `:var` in the second session to import results.

```
#+name: make_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *one* :results output
_gpg_tmpdir="$( mktemp -d )"
echo $_gpg_tmpdir
#+end_src
```

```
#+RESULTS: make_temporary_directories
: /tmp/tmp.iAE5oSlwcC
```

```
#+name: clean_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *two* :var gpg_tmpdir=make_temporary_directories :results output
echo $gpg_tmpdir
#+end_src
```

Comment: Ok. The next question is: how to share results of one bash script in another? I want to tangle different logical sessions to different scripts.

Comment: ... and how to get rid of `PS1` in results (I don't know why I get it):
: trupanka@loststation ~/CLASSES/_PLAYGROUND/BASH $ /tmp/tmp.7QMo1uK8Up

Comment: ask your next question as a new question, the short answer is to use the `:tangle` header arg to send different babel blocks to different files.